# Include a dictionary of path directory to json file recommendation python ways

Tags: python, json

This might be a very simple question but I wanted to get a good recommendation other than the below way of loading a json path directory.

```
Directory Path: "C:\\Users\\anonymous\\env_name\\project_name\\data"
```

Is there a better way of specifying the path instead of using `"\\"` but `"\"` only? I tried `r"C:\Users\anonymous\env_name\project_name\data"` but it won't work. Thank you

Comment: is above something in JSON or Python?  i.e. is it a path you defined in JSON file and you want to read it out in Python; Or is it a path to a (JSON, or anything else) file that you want to open in Python?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. the above file will be in JSON, which will be loaded by python.

Comment: Then, no, there is nothing as "raw string" in JSON.  `r"blababla"` is raw string literal in Python, which has nothing to do with what you put in JSON.  An alternative is to use `/` instead of `\` as directory separator, as it should be valid for most languages to use `/` even on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory, that was saved as a raw string is a fully valid directory path.
It should work, as long as the "thing" you are using it for is does not take in something weird.
Note: Maybe try "/" and make sure that it is a raw string, or double up the "/". Also, you usually will not need this, but, in some cases, you will need a "/" at the end (but that is rare).
Hope that helped.